# How to merge old subscription with new subscription in stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

Earlier, We have separate subscription for every products. And we came to know that we can create single subscription with multiple product by creating subscription with subscription items. Now we need to combine old subscription with new subscription's item. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always update existing subscriptions with [new items](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-items). You don't have to worry about old items on that subscription since this API will create new items and add them to that subscription.

On the other hand, if you pass the [id](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-items-id) of an existing item, you will be able to update its price as described in this Stripe [guide](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/upgrade-downgrade).

With this in mind, I would recommend you updating one of  the subscriptions to add new items with Prices from the other subscription. Note that there are many options in Stripe for how or if to prorate and charge for the changes to the two subscriptions, so be sure to experiment in test mode to find what matches your needs.